# django связи таблиц Каталог и Товары

Tags: python, django

Есть 2 модели, как сделать так что бы выводились только категории в которых есть товары. Сейчас выводятся все категории

```
class CatalogList(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10)
    name = models.TextField()
    sortingOrder = models.IntegerField()

class Items(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10)
    name = models.TextField()
    imageurl = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ForeignKey(CatalogList, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='item_list', db_column='category')
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение на данный момент

```
class Catalog():

def list():
    catalog_list = []
    for Cat in CatalogList.objects.all().order_by('sortingOrder'):
        if CatalogList.objects.filter(item_list__category=Cat.code).count() > 0:
            catalog_list.append(Cat)

    return iter(catalog_list)
```